# Unable to update desktop background

Tags: macos, desktop

I currently have an issue changing the background image on my Mac.

Every time I open up the preferences it shows this question mark, no matter what I select as an image, (my own, a pre installed, solid colour) it never updates or saves.

I presume something is corrupted on machine but I don't know where to look to fix it.

[image]

Update: Mac Version 10.15.6

Comment: Please add the version of macOS to your original question.